# Investigate a Valgrind Invalid Read

Tags: c, struct, valgrind, memory-alignment

When I run my [project](https://github.com/montao/openshell) with [valgrind](/questions/tagged/valgrind) I get an error report. If I don't use Valgrind then the program appears normal, but I'm certain that there is something wrong when Valgrind reports it.

```
==21286== Invalid read of size 4
==21286==    at 0x404950: fork_pipeline (util.c:296)
==21286==    by 0x403149: execute_pipeline (main.c:177)
==21286==    by 0x4032D5: run_cmd (main.c:221)
==21286==    by 0x403CC3: command (main.c:622)
==21286==    by 0x402B01: main (main.c:933)
==21286==  Address 0x593be68 is 0 bytes after a block of size 24 alloc'd
==21286==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==21286==    by 0x4031DD: run_cmd (main.c:204)
==21286==    by 0x403CC3: command (main.c:622)
==21286==    by 0x402B01: main (main.c:933)
```

The offending [main.c:204](https://github.com/montao/openshell/blob/master/main.c#L204) is the line

```
`struct pipeline *pipe = malloc(chunks->pipes * sizeof *pipe);`
```

but I don't understand what is wrong with it. If I inspect the value of `pipes` then it seems correct. The surrounding code is:

```
int run_cmd(const char *cmd) {

    char buffer[2];
    buffer[0] = '|';
    buffer[1] = '\0';
    struct str_list *chunks = list_split(cmd, buffer);
    struct pipeline *pipe = malloc(chunks->pipes * sizeof *pipe);
    pipe->data = malloc(sizeof(char *));
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < chunks->pipes; i++) {
        pipe[i].data = malloc(sizeof(char *) * BUFFER_SIZE * chunks[i].size);
        int j = 0;
        pipe[i].size = chunks[i].size;
        for (j = 0; j < chunks[i].size; j++) {
            if (chunks[i].argv[j] == NULL) {
                chunks[i].argv[j] = '\0';
                break;
            }
            pipe[i].data[j] = strdup(chunks[i].argv[j]);
            pipe[i].option[0] = chunks[i].option[i];
        }
        pipe[i].data[j] = '\0';
    }
    int status = execute_pipeline(chunks->pipes, pipe);
    return status;
}
```

If I look in a debugger, then the values look ok. My idea now is to put in assertions so that I can find where the error appears.

The struct has this declaration.

```
struct str_list {
    char *name;
    int size;
    int pipes;
    char **argv;
    int option[];

};
```

The second struct is

```
struct pipeline {
    char *name;
    int size;
    char **data;
    int option[];
};
```

### Update / edit

I changed the code according to the answer.

```
int run_cmd(const char *cmd) {

    char buffer[2];
    buffer[0] = '|';
    buffer[1] = '\0';
    struct str_list *chunks = list_split(cmd, buffer);
    struct pipeline *pipe = malloc(chunks->pipes * sizeof *pipe);
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < chunks->pipes; i++) {
        pipe[i].data = malloc(sizeof(char **) * BUFFER_SIZE * chunks[i].size);
        int j = 0;
        pipe[i].size = chunks[i].size;
        for (j = 0; j < chunks[i].size; j++) {
            if (chunks[i].argv[j] == NULL) {
                chunks[i].argv[j] = '\0';
                break;
            }
            pipe[i].data[j] = strdup(chunks[i].argv[j]);
            pipe[i].option[0] = chunks[i].option[i];
        }
        pipe[i].data[j] = '\0';
    }
    int status = execute_pipeline(chunks->pipes, pipe);
    return status;
}
```

Still getting invalid read.

```
==23103== Invalid write of size 4
==23103==    at 0x403278: run_cmd (main.c:216)
==23103==    by 0x403CB3: command (main.c:621)
==23103==    by 0x402B01: main (main.c:932)
==23103==  Address 0x592e228 is 0 bytes after a block of size 24 alloc'd
==23103==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23103==    by 0x4031DD: run_cmd (main.c:204)
==23103==    by 0x403CB3: command (main.c:621)
==23103==    by 0x402B01: main (main.c:932)
==23103== 
==23104== Invalid read of size 4
==23104==    at 0x404940: fork_pipeline (util.c:296)
==23104==    by 0x403149: execute_pipeline (main.c:177)
==23104==    by 0x4032C5: run_cmd (main.c:220)
==23104==    by 0x403CB3: command (main.c:621)
==23104==    by 0x402B01: main (main.c:932)
==23104==  Address 0x592e228 is 0 bytes after a block of size 24 alloc'd
==23104==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23104==    by 0x4031DD: run_cmd (main.c:204)
==23104==    by 0x403CB3: command (main.c:621)
==23104==    by 0x402B01: main (main.c:932)
```

Row 216: `pipe[i].option[0] = chunks[i].option[i];`

Row 204: `struct pipeline *pipe = malloc(chunks->pipes * sizeof *pipe);`

Comment: Why are you clobbering `pipe->data` with a memory allocated value to hold of type `char *` and further on,in the `for` loop, `malloc` it?

Comment: @t0mm13b If I don't malloc it then I get an error at `pipe[i].option[0] = chunks[i].option[i];`. I'm new to this detailed level of C so maybe you know? I understand that I should malloc dynamic memory, but the structures have 3 levels and I'm not sure how to malloc a struct with it's members.

Comment: Please show the declaration of the `struct pipe`

Comment: @t0mm13b Ok. Now you got it.

Comment: don't see anything relating to `data` member?

Comment: @t0mm13b I added the code for the second struct that has the `data` member.

Comment: when calling any of the memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans:  1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.  2) insert appropriate comments in the code, so the reader knows what the writer is trying to perform.   3) include the `#include` statements in the posted code so we do not have to guess.  4) include the prototypes for the 'homegrown' functions, so we can compare parameters and returned values.

Comment: the code:`pipe->data = `and `pipe[i].data` looks very suspicious . It looks like lines such as: `pipe[i].data[j] = '\0';` are accessing the data[] array past its' end, Which is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event and/or corrupted data.

Comment: these three lines: `char buffer[2];
    buffer[0] = '|';
    buffer[1] = '\0';`  can be reduced to: `char buffer[] ="|";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have it, you're using a flexible array for your `option`'s field in both `struct str_list` and `struct pipeline`.

You have to account for that space with allocating for your struct's.  I have compiled and run your code but, I changed:

```
struct pipeline {
    char *name;
    int size;
    char **data;
    int *option; // pointer to int
};
```

and:

```
struct str_list {
    char *name;
    int size;
    int pipes;
    char **argv;
    int *option; // pointer to int

};
```

Doing so you need to make sure you add in `malloc` calls for this pointer.

```
struct str_list *chunks = list_split(cmd, buffer);
struct pipeline *pipe = malloc(chunks->pipes * sizeof *pipe);
pipe->data = malloc(sizeof(char *));
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < chunks->pipes; i++) {
    pipe[i].data = malloc(sizeof(char *) * BUFFER_SIZE * chunks[i].size);
    int j = 0;
    pipe[i].size = chunks[i].size;
    for (j = 0; j < chunks[i].size; j++) {
        if (chunks[i].argv[j] == NULL) {
            chunks[i].argv[j] = '\0';
            break;
        }
        pipe[i].option = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10); // However many options...
        chunks[i].option = malloc(sizeof(int) * 10); // However many options...
        chunks[i].option[i] = 0;
        pipe[i].data[j] = strdup(chunks[i].argv[j]);
        pipe[i].option[0] = chunks[i].option[i];
```

I checked out the `util.c` file in the `list_split` function you never set the `option` field, so I explicitly initialize `chunks[i].option[i] = 0`.

After these changes those valgrind no longer is spitting out those errors but, you still have quite a few memory leaks that showed.

Comment: Thank you very much. This answer really helped. Yes, I have some memory leaks left but we solved the problem I was asking about.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the *valgrind* output,

It seems that memory allocating to hold `pipe->data` **initially**, with a quantity reflected by type `char *` (*on x86 platforms*, it is usually 1 byte, on others it could vary as implementation defined by compiler and platform), then in the `for` loop, call `malloc` with the actual bytes.

Remove the `malloc`on the initial call.

```
pipe->data = malloc(sizeof(char *));
```

**Bonus** This will remove the potential memory leak

**EDIT**

So `data` is a "dynamic array of strings"

in the `for` loop:

```
pipe[i].data = malloc(sizeof(char *) * BUFFER_SIZE * chunks[i].size);
```

Change that to:

```
pipe[i].data = malloc(sizeof(char **) * BUFFER_SIZE * chunks[i].size);
```

Comment: Which one should I remove and how should it look like? `struct pipeline *pipe = malloc(chunks->pipes * sizeof *pipe);` or `pipe->data = malloc(sizeof(char *));` ? It seems nothing is possible when I try. If I comment out `pipe->data = malloc(sizeof(char *));` then I still get error.

Comment: @Programmer400 Edited my answer

Comment: Thanks, but now I get Invalid read of size 4 for the row `struct pipeline *pipe = malloc(chunks->pipes * sizeof *pipe);`. I don't know if that is better.

Comment: Where is data, do not see it? FYI size 4 is triggering off, an int, usually on 32bit platform, its 4 bytes, henceforth. Please update code to reflect.

Comment: `char **data;` right at the bottom of my question, last line of code.

Comment: If I change to `pipe[i].data = malloc(sizeof(char **) * BUFFER_SIZE * chunks[i].size);` then I get invalid read of size 4 for the line `struct pipeline *pipe = malloc(chunks->pipes * sizeof *pipe);`. It feels hopeless. No matter what I do I get a valgrind error. `Address 0x592e228 is 0 bytes after a block of size 24 alloc'd` for the struct.

Comment: `sizeof *pipe`, a small test, do a `printf("sizeof *pipe = %d\n", sizeof *pipe);`immediately *after* the `malloc` call, run it and see, tell me the result. Hang on, should that be `pipes` **not** *pipe* ?

Comment: It says `sizeof *pipe = 24` when I include the test immediately after `struct pipeline *pipe = malloc(chunks->pipes * sizeof *pipe);`.

Comment: There seems to be some confusion, `struct pipeline *pipe` vs `struct pipeline`, saw there's a member `pipe` too....

Comment: Yes, I have too much going on in the code. I named a pipeline a pipe, that is supposed to be a list a pipelines representing a command list. I can run the program and get the correct output but I'm sure there's something wrong because Valgrind is not mistaken.

Comment: **What** is `*pipe`? you declared a variable `pipe`, as per  `struct pipeline *pipe = malloc(chunks->pipes * sizeof *pipe);` and have this referenced as `sizeof *pipe`? Should that not be `sizeof *pipeline`?

Comment: I might be doing it wrong, but I tried allocating it like `struct st *x = malloc(sizeof *x);`. `*pipe` is supposed to be a pointer to a struct if I understand correctly. Did I misunderstand? Is there anything odd about the code? Isn't the struct allocated properly?

Comment: Should I just give up?

Comment: @Programmer400 absolutely not ;)

Comment: Now it is complaining on three rows but the error msg is shorter. I don't think that the code is absolutely wrong because the output is correct. I think that I'm doing some allocation wrong. I can update the question again with the exact details if that helps.